# Removing an object from a vector based on a member function from the object

Tags: c++, object, vector

I am having trouble creating a erase-remove idiom to remove an object from a vector based on the results of a function of that object.

Example, I have an vector here:

```
std::vector<Entity*> bulletEnemyObjects;
```

that stores objects of type Entity which each have a variable

```
bool alive;
```

that is accessed by a function in the object's class

```
bool Entity::GetAlive()
{
    return alive;
}
```

I need to iterate through the vector, and remove any objects that return false to the GetAlive() function. Any help possible here?

Comment: lol you can't create that idiom it already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make your GetAlive function const.

```
bulletEnemyObjects.erase(remove_if(bulletEnemyObjects.begin(), bulletEnemyObjects.end(), [](const Entity* entity){ return ! entity->GetAlive(); }), bulletEnemyObjects.end());
```

Note that this will not delete the entity object pointed to. You may or may not need to do this. It also assumes there are no null pointers.

Comment: Is there no way for the function not to be const? GetAlive is set to false based on events, having it as const defeats the purpose of the variable.

Comment: No, `GetAlive` can be non-const. As you see, the type of `bulletEnemyObjects` is `std::vector<Entity*>`, not `std::vector<const Entity*>`

Comment: @FireFreak111 You can remove the `const` from my code snippet. But GetAlive being const only means that calling this function won't change the object. It doesn't mean the value returned can't change between calls. If it only returns a value, you should make it const.

Comment: @ikh Can, but shouldn't.

Comment: @NeilKirk I guessed the *real* `GetAlive` of OP's code has some reason for non-const; But after some thought, it seems no >o<

Comment: I Implemented this 
`void GameState::ClearObjects(std::vector<Entity*> &vector)
{
 vector.erase(remove_if(vector.begin(), vector.end(), [](Entity* entity){ return !entity->GetAlive(); }));
}`

but I get a vector erase iterator out of range error.

Comment: @FireFreak111 Notice I made a correction to my code. I missed a parameter.

Comment: There we go, thankyou for the correction :). Works perfectly. Will need to seriously look into lambadas.

Comment: @FireFreak111 Cool! But add that const!

Comment: The Get function is designed to safely return a variable and not modify a thing. Any Get function won't modify. I don't believe I should be concerned due to this.

Comment: @FireFreak111 What happens if you make a mistake in your code and call a function which modifies the entity, where it shouldn't be modified? Using const pointers prevents mistakes, but needs you to tell the compiler which functions don't modify.

Answer (score 1):

`erase`-`remove_if`.

```
bulletEnemyObjects.erase(
    std::remove_if(bulletEnemyObjects.begin(), bulletEnemyObjects.end(),
        [](Entity *p) { return !p->GetAlive(); }
        ),
    bulletEnemyObjects.end()
    );
```

[(live example)](http://ideone.com/Q4XcNm)

Comment: @FireFreak111 this is called the erase-remove idiom for future reference.